# Users being prompted with apple add on pop up in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, tinymce, umbraco, add-on

When a user visits our site whilst using IE they are prompted to run the apple quick time add on.

I wish to stop this from happening, is there anything that anyone can think of that would be causing this. There is nothing on the site that would even require quicktime to run except for TinyMCE which is used on the backend only.

The site is built on umbraco 6 cms.

Comment: Why would you vote it down? I thought this was the place to come when you needed assistance?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really anything to do with Umbraco. On your page somewhere, you'll have a quicktime plugin embedded. That'll be what's causing the popup. As far as I know, Umbraco has no dependency on Quicktime. Look through your front end code for any obvious embed code, check JS files as well to see if it's being loaded in dynamically.

I'm assuming they're getting the popup on the front end, and not in the back end?

Comment: Yes they are getting the pop-up on the front end

Comment: try viewing your page's source and searching for `mp4`, `mov`, `quicktime`, `applet` etc to find the offender.